# mysqli_query does not run query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have these .php files:

in db_functions saveData does not run the sqliquery. it does not insert the parameter into database - i've tested same query on phpmyadmin (with random values) - it works - but here it does not... is there any error in the code? db_config data is right - only changed them to xxx :D

db_config:

```
    <?php


define("DB_HOST", "xxx");
define("DB_USER", "xxx");
define("DB_PASSWORD", "xxx");
define("DB_DATABASE", "xxx");

?>
```

db_connect:

```
    <?php

class DB_CONNECT {

    private $conn;

    // constructor
    function __construct() {


    }


    /**
     * Function to connect with database
     */
    function connect() {
        // import database db variables
        require_once __DIR__ . '/db_config.php';

        // Connecting to mysql database
       $this->conn = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }
        // Selecing database

        // returing connection cursor
        return $this->conn;
    }



}

?>
```

db_functions

```
class DB_Functions {

    private $conn;

    //put your code here
    // constructor
    function __construct() {
        include_once './db_connect.php';
        // connecting to database
        $db = new DB_Connect();
          $this->conn = $db->connect();
    }






    public function saveData($name, $id) {


    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
  exit();
}
        // insert user into database
            $query = "INSERT INTO data(name, id) VALUES('$name','$id')";
            echo $query;
        $result = mysqli_query($this->conn,$query);

...}
```

Comment: What are the values of `$name` and `$id`? Note that you could easily catch the occurring exception and check the error message. Note that you're vulnerable to [SQL-injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and should be using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php). You might also want to consider an auto incrementer in your table but that's sort of off-topic but it enables you to not having to think about the id.

Comment: add code to check the value of $result, and if false, call mysqli_error() and see what you get! And yes, what @Jonast92 says: DO NOT directly put strings into the INSERT statement. Use placeholders and bound parameters...

Comment: i post the values with a formular like "test" for name and "2" for id... with echo I can see that the values are received right - but however the query does not run... even if i insert $query = "blablabla" no error appears..

Comment: @RobP can you give me an example for "Use placeholders and bound parameters..."

Comment: @Steve Are you even checking for errors? They won't just magically appear, you have to check for them.

Comment: @Steve I already linked to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) :)

Comment: Use the prepare method on your query, with special placeholders where the values go, to get a statement object. Then call mysqli's bind_param on the statement passing in the values you want, and execute. Placeholders can be `?` or named placeholders like `:name`. More info at http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php

Comment: like Paolo answered the error was the missing parameter here:

$this->conn = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD); changed to
$this->conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);

Comment: @RobP ah you mean the object mysqli object oriented way right?

Comment: @Steve no, you can use procedural or object calls, either way, that's a different distinction. I mean that you use bound parameters. Did you read the documentation?

Comment: yes -> I changed the code to  $stmt= $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO data(name, id) VALUES(?, ?);
  $stmt-> bind_param("si", $name, $id);
  $stmt-> execute();
  $stmt-> bind_result ($result);
  $stmt-> close();

but something with bind_result does not work... @RobP

Comment: @Steve post that as a new question. hint: after execute, try fetch...

Comment: *"but something with bind_result does not work"* - More than likely a scope issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this line

```
$this->conn = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
```

where `DB_SERVER` is not defined and you're not passing the database name

so it should be

```
$this->conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
```

I don't see any other evident mistake in your code.
However I strongly suggest to use prepared statements instead of injecting the data right into the query.

See [mysqli::prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

Comment: yes: $this->conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
 did it :)

the problem with DB_SERVER != DB_HOST was my fault while typing the wrong value^^